# Dynamically filtering clientdataset content

Tags: delphi, n-tier-architecture, datasnap

I'm asking myself a question about the way to filter content of a clientdataset in a 3 tier datasnap architecture : `Oracle DB <=> My Datasnap Server <=> My Datasnap clients`

I have a Oracle table accessed thru a [`TDSProviderConnection`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Datasnap.DSConnect.TDSProviderConnection) and a [`TClientDataset`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TClientDataSet).

Multiple clients are using the dataset, which contains a field named `"clientId"`.
I would like each client to request only his rows (just like `WHERE clientId = 'Client1'` in a sql statement).

If I understant right, use of filter doesn't not reduce overhead.

```
myclientdataset.Filter:= 'ClientId = Client1';
myclientdataset.Filtered:= true;
```

As this pass all the client anyway. I want the server to filter what's sent.

But I have no idea how to accomplish this using these components.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
JP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a task for a parametrized query as described in [this etutorial](http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+16+Multitier+DataSnap+Applications/Advanced+DataSnap+Features/). As each client sets its own parameter only the requested data is transferred to each client.

Answer (score 0):

The Filter property filters the contents that have been loaded into the ClientDataSet. It does not have any influence on the data that you retrieve from the underlying database.

To have the ClientDataSet influence the data retrieved from an underlying relational database, you can either specify a query in the CommandText property, or include a parameterized query (or stored procedure call) in the CommandText property and then use the Params property to define the values of your parameters.